# Blender 2.72 No Cycles Hair Rendering/Settings Tabs

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, particles

I have tried blender versions from 2.69 to present and have yet to see the Cycles Hair Rendering or Settings Tabs.

My steps
1.  New blender project with the cube present
2.  Go to particles and hit +
3.  Choose Type: Hair

and no Cycle Hair tabs??
My crazy cube hair renders just fine, but the Cycle Hair tabs are never visible.  Am I missing a setting somewhere?

[image: simpleBlenderNotTabs]

Comment: In the upper left corner, where it says Blender Render, change to Cycles Render.

Comment: Perfect!  That is what I was missing!!  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the top of your screenshot, you will notice that the render engine is still set to the Blender default, which is Blender Internal. You need to select Cycles as the render engine.

[image]

Now all the settings appear as expected.

[image]